# Python define a function to plot the column

Tags: python, function, plot

I want to create a function where it will plot the CO2_emission and another indicator (which is selected by user).

```
def CO2_indicator(driver, df = CO2_driver):
    # create plot
    fig = px.scatter(
        df, 
        x = df['CO2_emission_pc'],
        y = df[driver],     
        hover_name = 'country',


    )
    
    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis_title = driver,                         
        xaxis_title = 'CO2_emission_pc',                         
        title = 'Relationship between CO2 emission per capita and ' + driver, 
        title_x = 0.5,      
        margin = {'l' : 0, 'r' : 0}
    )

    return fig
```

i run the function :

```
CO2_indicator(forest_area, df = CO2_driver ) #(forest_area is the indicator)
```

[enter image description here][2]

The wrong is in the orange part, it cant subset the column forest_area in the dataframe. It must be df['forest_area'] (i mean put it into quotation)
How can I solve this? Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENW19.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/APYU5.png

Comment: You've got a key error, I guess what the variable `forest_area` contains does not exist in the `df`.

Answer (score 0):

[see this image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdoFZ.png) and try the following code , I hope that help you :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("FuelConsumption.csv") #assum this DataFram you use
cdf =df[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_CITY','FUELCONSUMPTION_HWY','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB','CO2EMISSIONS']]
CO2EMISSIONS = cdf.CO2EMISSIONS
def func (user_selected):
    plt.scatter(user_selected, CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
    plt.xlabel("CO2EMISSIONS")
    plt.ylabel("{}".format(user_selected.name))
    plt.show()
```

then call function :

```
func(cdf.CYLINDERS)
```